# Python fetching webpage data

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that fetches the html from the tv catchup website, then uses the split function to split up all the html data into just the channel name and the program that is currently on in a table, such as: BBC 1 - 'program name'. I just need help on what i do after my first split function if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2
import string


proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "http://c99.cache.e2bn.org:8084"})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

tvCatchup = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.TVcatchup.com')

html = tvCatchup.read()

firstSplit = html.split('<a class="enabled" href="/watch.html?c=')[1:]
for i in firstSplit:
    print i

secondSplit = html.split ('1" title="BBC One"></a></li><li class="v-type" style="color:#6d6d6d;">')[1:]

for i in secondSplit:
print i
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't split the output, but use some kind of HTML parser. [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a screen scraper, rather than substringing HTML. A good screen scraping tool is [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), which uses XPATHs to retrieve the data.

The [Scrapy at a glance](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/overview.html) page is useful. It provides a complete example of how to extract data from a webpage.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use urllib2.
Use Requests instead
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

For html parsing use BeautifulSoup
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

**Note : It seems that this proxy is down, remove proxy settings, and it works**

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

proxyDict = {"http":"http://c99.cache.e2bn.org:8084"}
r = requests.get("http://www.TVcatchup.com", proxies=proxyDict)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
tvs = list()

uls = soup.findAll("ul", { "class":"channels2"}
for ul in uls:
   div = ul.find("div")
   if div:
       showid = div.get("showid")
       link = ul.find("a")
       href = link.get("href")
       title = link.get("title")
       tvs.append({"showid":showid, "href":href, "title":title})
print tvs
```

you'll get this

```
[{'showid': u'450263', 'href': u'/watch.html?c=1', 'title': u'BBC One'}, 
{'showid': u'450353', 'href': u'/watch.html?c=2', 'title': u'BBC Two'}, 
{'showid': u'450398', 'href': u'/watch.html?c=3', 'title': u'ITV1'}, 
{'showid': u'450521', 'href': u'/watch.html?c=4', 'title': u'Channel 4'},...
```

Comment: Because this is school work, that's the only reason i used those as they are the ones we have been taught to use when manipulating webpages. Also just to make it clear the proxy handler is so the program can actually access the internet when at school through the proxy

Comment: I'm currently writing you a whole code, give me a minute please :)

Comment: Ok thanks, it's just the main thing i was confused on is how to i create a list of the html, itter over the list and remove the rest of the html, that's what i have no idea of what to do

Comment: Ah :) I'll help you give me few more min :)

Comment: Ok thanks, i won't be on here till after 3 because my study periods are over but thanks for the help :)

Comment: "please don't use urllib2" - why? It is a perfectly good library for fetching a website. Also, the alternative you linked returns a 404. Downvoted...

Comment: I will quote "Kenneth Reitz". "Most existing Python modules for sending HTTP requests are extremely verbose and cumbersome. Python's builtin urllib2 module provides most of the HTTP capabilities you should need, but the api is thoroughly broken. It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks."

Comment: Please remove proxy and it will work, where do you think i got that dictionary? It's not my job to check if proxy is online or not

Comment: A short google search for the library shows that you forgot an 's' in the module url (`/requestS`, not `/request`). And quoting the maintainer of the module for reasons why you should use his module is not exactly a compelling argument. The built-in library works just fine for OPs use case, so recommending to introduce an external dependency *that he doesn't even need* is an extremely bad advice.

Comment: Thanks i changed the url, when it comes to not recommending a external dependecy, that is another story and no point in fighting over it. Have a nice day